# Reshape data from long to wide in R

Tags: r, pivot-table, tidyr

My data look like this

| Person ID | Treatment code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 00001 |
| A | 00002 |
| A | 00003 |
| B | 00002 |
| B | 00012 |
| C | 00003 |
| C | 00015 |

Each patient can have an infinite number of treatment.
What I would like is a line for each patient with as much columns as the maximum number of treatment a patient can have. And, in each column of treatment, the corresponding code.

| Pateint Id | Treatment 1 | Treatment 2 | Treatment 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 00001 | 00002 | 00003 |
| B | 00002 | 00012 | missing |
| C | 00003 | 00015 | missing |

I used to do this very easily in Stata but I am now struggling with R. I have tried to use the tidyr package and the `pivot_wider` function but did not succeed.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What have you tried with `pivot_wider()` and why it did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this could look like a clear duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format), there is a missing link. Before we start pivoting we need to obtain the row number per group.

E.g.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  group_by(PersonID) |> 
  mutate(name = row_number()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "PersonID", 
              values_from = "Treatmentcode",
              names_prefix = "Treatment")
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  PersonID Treatment1 Treatment2 Treatment3
  <chr>    <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1 A        00001      00002      00003     
2 B        00002      00012      NA        
3 C        00003      00015      NA
```

Data:

```r
library(readr)

df <- read_table("PersonID  Treatmentcode
A   00001
A   00002
A   00003
B   00002
B   00012
C   00003
C   00015")
```

Comment: It has worked, thanks. I actually missed the part where the data are first grouped by person ID. However. I am not sure to understand how the ```name``` variable is considered in ```pivot_wider()```?

Comment: It's the standard parameter for the`names_from`-argument.